# How to set value in text box using pywinauto?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pywin32, pywinauto, pywin

I am new to pywinauto and I don't know how to use control identifiers.

[image: sample Image]

[image: control identifier for textbox]

How would I set `No. of loops:` to 99999?

Answer (score 5):

For dynamic edit box you can use label text as a part of identifier. Examples:

```
app.WindowName.No__of_loops_Edit.set_text('99999')
# or
app.WindowName['No. of loops:Edit'].set_text('99999')

# for more realistic typing char by char:
app.WindowName['No. of loops:Edit'].type_keys('99999')
```

It's described in more details in the [Getting Started Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#how-to-know-magic-attribute-names) (section "How to know magic attribute names").