# How to click button in dialog box using PyWinAuto

Tags: python, pywinauto

I have an batch file that I execute that opens a program. A dialog box then appears which I type into it the username and password credentials

The I print the control identifiers and it lists;

```
SunAwtDialog - 'Login'    (L528, T242, R853, B501)
['SunAwtDialog', 'LoginSunAwtDialog', 'Login']
child_window(title="Login", class_name="SunAwtDialog")
```

So after reading this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41343648/how-to-set-value-in-text-box-using-pywinauto). My understanding was to use window + the button and a click method like so;

```
dlp.SunAwtDialog['Login'].click()
```

But this keeps throwing an `ElementNotFoundError`;

```
ElementNotFoundError: {'best_match': 'SunAwtDialog', 'top_level_only': False, 'parent': <win32_element_info.HwndElementInfo - 'Login', SunAwtDialog, 2164976>, 'backend': 'win32'}
```

Below is the full snippet of code;

```
from pywinauto import application
import time
app = application.Application()
app.start(r"C:\\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe", wait_for_idle=False)
dlg = app.top_window()
dlg.type_keys('D:{ENTER}')
dlg.type_keys('cd{SPACE}Software\\client{ENTER}')
dlg.type_keys('run_client.bat{ENTER}')
time.sleep(10)
new_app = application.Application().connect(title="iManager")
dlp = new_app.top_window()
#type username + password
dlp.type_keys('user')
dlp.type_keys('{TAB}')
dlp.type_keys('pass')
#print control identifiers
dlp.print_control_identifiers()
#click login[![enter image description here][1]][1]
dlp.SunAwtDialog['Login'].click()
```

You can see on the image below the "Login" button I want to be able to click. There is also another button next to the "Server" option, but it is not in my control identifiers

[image: Dialog box]

Comment: You can see in the error that `'backend': 'win32'`. You may try to use `Application(backend="uia")` and `Inspect.exe` as a spy tool. This is all described in the [Getting Started Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html).

Comment: This issue with that was that when I attempted it with `backend="uia"` it threw an error saying `ElementNotEnabled`

Comment: Sorry @VasilyRyabov ignore me, got the correct control identifiers up now. Also another question, if it needs to be moved to a separate one please let me know. But does this package work well with a java built application? As I had problems with the last tool I was using and that was specific to RPA

Comment: It depends which Java framework was used to build the GUI. As I remember JavaFX supports MS UI Automation API pretty well (yes, it's OS level API, pywinauto just wraps it around with some syntax sugar). Not sure about Swing/AWT apps as they are pretty old.

Comment: `Inspect.exe` uses MS UI Automation API as well (you need to switch to "UI Automation" mode). This is almost the only indicator of GUI testability now.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it `Inspect.exe` out as at the moment, the only button I can get to click is the `Cancel` button.

Answer (score 1):

A solution that I use for this is using send_keys. Try this:

```
from pywinauto.keyboard import send_keys
send_keys("{VK_MENU down}" "l" "{VK_MENU up}")
```

Answer (score 0):

The good solution for this is pressing the "Enter" if there is only an "OK" button on that Dialog/Message/Alert/Information box. For this you can use:

```
send_keys("{ENTER}")
```

If that doesn't work correctly, you can use the sleep command to wait for 1-2 seconds and then press enter, like so:

```
time.sleep(2)
send_keys("{Enter}")
```

For this, you have to import two libraries:

```
from pywinauto.keyboard import send_keys
import time
```